# Getting an error when using 'make' command (installing aircrack-ng on Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, compiling, make, aircrack-ng

I followed [these instructions](http://securit.se/en/2012/03/kompilera-reaver-ubuntu-12-04/). I edited the `common.mak` file successfully and when I ran `make` I get this error:

```
mohd-arafat-hossain@TUD:~/aircrack-ng-1.1$ make
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'
make -C osdep
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
Building for Linux
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[3]: `.os.Linux' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -Iinclude   -c -o aircrack-ng.o aircrack-ng.c
In file included from aircrack-ng.c:65:0:
crypto.h:12:26: fatal error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [aircrack-ng.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mohd-arafat-hossain/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error says you don't have ssl header files. So just install them.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: When compiling the most important is get the -dev packages of the libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Download `openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz` and build it twice.

```
./config  --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make && make install  

./config shared --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make clean
make && make install
```

In the first time:it will build the `*.so` lib file.

The second ,it will build the include `*.h` file.

It's useful.

Comment: Pre built library is already available in repository

Comment: Your solution might work, it is just way less hassle using apt than compiling and maintaining it from source